# corona addEventListener issue

Tags: lua, coronasdk

```
local function composeConfession()
   print("composeConfession()") 
end 

function displyHomeScreen()
    local composeBtn=display.newImageRect("images/composeBtn.jpeg", 30, 30)
    composeBtn:addEventListerner("tap", composeConfession)
end
```

Am calling displyHomeScreen() from main as it is globle & created a button, assigned  composeConfession() listener on it now the error it is showing is

error:

File: /Users/nashad/Desktop/JustInMind/homeScreen.lua
Line: 32

Attempt to call method 'addEventListerner' (a nil value)

Answer (score 2):

It is addEventListener not addEventListerner

Comment: thanx Dogancan my editor was not showing misspells what u use for it

Comment: Actually you can understad such errors from Corona Similator. Attempt to call method "something" ( a nil value ) means, attempt to call a function which doesn't exist. Keep in mind ;)

Comment: +1. Nice catch on the spelling. @Rais: If this answer has helped you solve your issue, please consider marking it as the accepted answer to indicate to future users with similar issues what has helped you in solving yours.

Comment: @DoğancanArabacı **Corona Simulator***